# Insert statement for table with primary key auto increment

Tags: mysql

I have created a table with a primary key of INT auto increment.
When I tried to insert data into the table I am not able to do so.
This is the error I faced: Unknown column 'status' in field list.
How should I go about doing it?

The code for creating table:

```
 CREATE TABLE item (
itemId INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
code VARCHAR(8),
status VARCHAR(32),
desc1 VARCHAR(128) DEFAULT NULL,
desc2 VARCHAR(128) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (itemId),
FOREIGN KEY (code) REFERENCES product (code)
  ) ENGINE INNODB;
```

The code for insert statement:

```
   INSERT INTO item (code, status, desc1, desc2) VALUES ('EX00001','In Stock','a','b');
```

The code for product table:

```
 CREATE TABLE product (
code VARCHAR(8),
productName VARCHAR(32),
productDesc VARCHAR(128),
unitPrice DECIMAL(18,4),
PRIMARY KEY (code)
```

) ENGINE INNODB;

Comment: is the error happening with create table or the insert?

Comment: post error ..you have FK integrity constraint ..its that violates?

Comment: this SQL Fiddle shows that works http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/defb0/1 (if I remove your FK constraint)

Comment: but I need the reference

Comment: you mean in product table?

Comment: i have edited the question with my code for product table

Comment: does your product table have a record with code `EX00001` ?

Comment: yes my product table have code EX00001

Comment: see this Fiddle. The code you've shown works http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e97e5/1

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28048/discussion-between-matt-busche-and-beny-lim)

Comment: hmm. Isn't it the same code?

Comment: yes, it's the same code. you either don't have a record in your products table or you haven't posted your exact code

Answer (score 0):

**Status** is a reserved word on Mysql.
[Show Status Mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/show-status.html)

You need to use quotes. try doing this:

```
CREATE TABLE item (
`itemId` INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
`code` VARCHAR(8),
`status` VARCHAR(32),
`desc1` VARCHAR(128) DEFAULT NULL,
`desc2` VARCHAR(128) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`itemId`),
FOREIGN KEY (code) REFERENCES product (`code`)
  ) ENGINE INNODB;
```

and when make the Select use also the single quotes;

```
select `status`,.... from ....
```